# Чому словосполучення "нанести шкоду" вважають неправильним?

Tags: правопис, словосполучення

Чому в українській мові правильно казати «завдати шкоди», «завдати збитків», а словосполучення «нанести шкоду» не є правильним?

Стаття http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/21.htm, свідчить, що шкоду не наносять, а завдають:

> Сьогодні часто кажуть і пишуть: нанести шкоду, нанести удар. Але це помилка. Шкоду, сором, образу, смуток, жаль, удар тощо не наносять, а завдають. Читаємо в класиків: “Не завдавай ти мені сорому при чужих людях” (Іван Нечуй-Левицький); “Щоб більше жаху їй завдать, і щоб усяк боявся так робити,— у річці вражу щуку утопити” (Леонід Глібов).

Такі ж відомості подають і декілька інших сайтів.

На сайті http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-yak-pravylno-skazaty-ukrayinskoyu-deyaki-movni-klishe/, кажуть що:

> наносити шкоду – завдавати шкоди;
>   В українській мові дієслово наносити вживається в таких значеннях, як-от: наносити фарбу на папір, понаносили бруду на килим, нанесли візит та ін.
>   Але шкоди (Род. відм., одн.) завдають,
>   наприклад:
>   Дощі та грози, які пройшли наприкінці травня – на початку червня 2014 р., завдали значної шкоди як посівам, так і ягідникам та фруктовим садам.

Незважаючи на це, вислів "нанести шкоду", часто можна почути на телебаченні і побачити в авторитетних газетах.

Тож, як правильно вживати це словосполучення?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словник дає позначку розмовне до значення, яке підходить до вашого питання. Це не неправильно, але і не літературна норма.

НАНОСИТИ

> 5. розм. У сполученні з деякими іменниками означає: заподіювати, чинити, робити те, на що вказує іменник. Уже більшого сорому вона не в
>      силі приспособити над той, який наносить їй її муж (Лесь Мартович,
>      Тв., 1954, 267); Вона все знає. Приміром.., що він має брата чи
>      родича, котрий йому багато прикростей.. наніс (Ольга Кобилянська, III,
>      1956, 335).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nanosyty)

Answer (score 2):

*Завдати шкоду* - мовне кліше, словосполучення, що відрізняється стійким лексичним складом. Наприклад, участь *беруть*, а не приймають, освіту *здобувають*, а не отримують. Його варіант - *вчинити шкоду*. Так само, як російському *нанести обиду* відповідає українське *заподіяти/вчинити образу*. Якщо калькувати з російської, без урахування значення слова в українській мові, можна створювати досить кумедні за змістом вислови.